# Electron: Install new version manually

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

I don't want to use `electron-updater` or other packages for updating my electron application so what are the solutions to update app manually?

I tried replacing built files of new version in `c:/program files/my-app` using a script but permission denied to paste files in this directory and only adminstrator access is permitted to paste in drive `c` of windows.

Comment: You mean for yourself? Just run the installer and it will update the app.

Comment: @Arkellys I don't want to run exe file to update. I want to update like telegram app which updates app by one click of user and starts new version of app without progress bar for installation and pressing next key in windows installation process.